# I am looking for testing framework which is capable of creating test scripts for smart contracts(solidity) automatically

Tags: solidity, testing

Is there any testing tool which is capable of handling smart contracts and can generate test scripts for given contracts based on function present in that contract?

End user only need to provide contract & test scenarios/cases to the tool from which test scripts should be auto generated without any human intervention.

Is it possible to develop such a tool?If yes, How?
Did any one worked/explore on this before?

Comment: A duplicate of your own question from a few days ago.

Comment: need more specific responses on this.

Comment: So explain it in the original question, don't post it twice.